# Sending android push notifications from your server

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, push

Please tell me if there are instructions on how to send a push notification from the server to android without any services.
Sending to ios goes something like this:

```
$tHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$tPort = 2195;
$tCert = '*';
$tPassphrase = '*';
$tToken = $token_user;
$tSound = 'default';
$tPayload = 'APNS payload';
$tBody['aps'] = array(
'badge' => +1,
'alert' => array(
    'title' => 'Новость',
    'body' => $name
    ),
'sound' => 'default'
);
$tBody ['payload'] = $tPayload;
$tBody = json_encode ($tBody);
$tContext = stream_context_create ();
stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $tCert);
stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $tPassphrase);
$tSocket = stream_socket_client ('ssl://'.$tHost.':'.$tPort, $error, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $tContext);
if (!$tSocket)
exit ("APNS Connection Failed: $error $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
$tMsg = chr (0) . chr (0) . chr (32) . pack ('H*', $tToken) . pack ('n', strlen ($tBody)) . $tBody;
$tResult = fwrite ($tSocket, $tMsg, strlen ($tMsg));
if ($tResult)
echo 'Delivered Message to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Could not Deliver Message to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
fclose ($tSocket);
```

P.S. I'm new to this business.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create an account in Firebase and enable cloud messaging. Once you get your keys, you can use FCM Server APIs to send a notification to your Android devices.
For more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging